# Find row and column indices of element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which look like this:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    0
```

Now, I want to find the row and column index of a specific element. For example for 5 I want to return 1 and 1. I am used to R where you can just use the `which` function for this. Does anyone know how to simply do this in python?

Comment: `np.where(df==5)`

Comment: `np.argwhere(df.values==5).tolist()`